# Set Kerberos KDC adress in C API without using krb5.conf file

Tags: c, linux, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I'm writing an C application which authenticate an user via MIT Kerberos.

`krb5_get_init_creds_password(..)` works fine, john.doe@EXAMPLE.COM can be authenticated, but i have to define

```
[realms]
    EXAMPLE.COM = {
        kdc = example.com
    }
```

in the `krb5.conf` file.

Is there any possibility for set the KDC server address in C API?

I do not want to use the `krb5.conf` file or make a environment setting.

Thanks in advance,
Darwin

Comment: What is the client OS?

Comment: Linux (on an embedded system)